# os.ftruncate() is showing some error while execution error like TypeError: a bytes-like object is required

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os,sys

sr=os.open("sri.txt",os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT)

os.write(sr,"This is the test-This is test")

os.ftruncate(sr,10)

os.lseek(sr,0,0)

str=os.read(sr,100)

print("Read string is:",str)

os.close(sr)

print("closed the file successfully!!")
```

Comment: I am having a lot of trouble believing that `ftruncate` is raising the error and not `write`.

Answer (score 0):

In python3 all strings are automatically Unicode.

So I can see two ways to fix it.

one is append "b" before writing the string as shown below.

```
os.write(sr,b"This is the test-This is test")
```

Or

Another is call encode() as shown below.

```
str = "This is the test-This is test"

ret = os.write(sr,str.encode())
```

For better understanding of strings behavior in python3 look into below tutorial

http://pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/